# Значение слова «пригоршня»

Tags: значение-слов

Есть фильм «За пригоршню долларов». Значение слова пытался найти в словарях, однако всё, что там было, не подходит по контексту. Что оно здесь означает? Может, - "малое количество" (по аналогии с "горсткой")?

Comment: Матвей, хватит редактировать мои сообщение. Ваши правки ни к чему не приводят, а зачастую даже искажают смысл. Не надо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь выражение в целом означает несоразмерно низкую плату (символическую, "смешную"), которую подрядчик, вероятно, назвать не удосужился и точно подсчитывать не стал бы (настолько хотел взяться за дело). Буквально, "**пригоршня**" здесь -  количество долларовых монет, которые можно зачерпнуть *двумя сложенными ладонями*. В оригинальном итальянском названии - "**горсть**" (un pugno), количество чего-то сыпучего *в одной ладони* лодочкой. В рецензиях того времени иронизировали, что фильм и снят был "за пригоршню долларов" - по аналогии придавали этим словам то же значение (отн. малое количество денег).